# How to add difference column to groupby statement in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this code:

```
print(ucla_all.groupby(['CPT Code']).agg(
    {'CPT Code': 'count', 'Average Charges':'mean','Average Reimbursement': 'mean'}))
```

And I have this table:

```
          CPT Code  Average Charges  Average Reimbursement
CPT Code                                                  
90792            1       490.000000             147.000000
90832            2       222.000000             222.000000
90833            3       148.000000             148.000000
90834           16       750.000000             750.000000
90837          286       422.472028             418.205350
90849          256       110.429688             110.429688
90853          207       130.000000             129.801836
```

How can I add another column with the difference between the second and third columns to this table with the groupby statement?

Comment: Why do you need to use the groupby? What are you grouping by?

Comment: Grouping by CPT code, as shown in the code above. If you know a better way to show the same results, please show me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save your grouped dataframe to a new variable name to distinguish it from your raw data. Then do a difference operation to add that new column.

```py
ucla_all_grouped = ucla_all.groupby(['CPT Code']).agg(
    {'CPT Code': 'count', 'Average Charges':'mean','Average Reimbursement': 'mean'})
ucla_all_grouped['Difference'] = ucla_all_grouped['Average Charge'] 
                                 - ucla_all_grouped['Average Reimbursement']
```

From experience, I find it good to distinguish raw dataframes and grouped dataframes from each other as you never know when to decide to do more analysis with one or start something new with the raw data.